# Recommended way in react hooks in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a question regarding the way to use the react hooks in react.

I have notice that some use in their files

```
const Users = () => {
  ....
 }
export default Users;
```

While others uses this instead

```
export default function Users(){
  ...
 }
```

What is the recommended/best way to do it?

Comment: this is not about react hooks

Comment: also, this code does the same thing

Comment: There's no difference. Both code examples export `Users` function as default export.

Comment: This is unrelated to React. Your're asking about the difference between a function and an arrow function.

Comment: @Yousaf There is a difference. For one thing, arrow functions do not have a `this` context while normal functions do. These are two different tools that, depending on use case, can be used interchangeably.

Comment: @JMadelaine as far as i can tell, question is about writing `export` statement on the same line where function is declared and writing `export` statement at the end of the module, not about arrow and regular functions

Comment: You're right, I'm just being a smart ass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more related to JavaScript (although the context is React function components).

```
const Users = () => {
  //....
 }
export default Users;

function Users() {
  //...
}
export default Users;

export default function Users(){
  //...
}

// Usage with auto-complete
import Users from './Users.js';
```

The **export effect** is the same, although there is a difference [between functions and arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable).

But using export like so we do have a more significant difference:

```
// Bad practice, don't do it!
// No auto-complete, no function name while debugging
export default () => {
  // Users logic
  //...
}

// No auto complete on typing Users, need to name the default export
import MyUsers from './Users.js';
```

Comment: Which of these do you frequently use?

Comment: The first one, `const Users = ...` and `export default Users`, but I believe that default exports are bad practice so I try only to use named exports. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Whatdo you mean? You're using named export here `export default users`

Comment: This is an answer, it doesn't mean that I use it. As I said I trying to only use named export `export const Users = ....`, but it's my opinion... Doesn't mean it the right thing to do.

Comment: how about `const Users`, `export default Users` VS `export default function Users`. I prefer the last cause you only use it in one line? Why would use the first one like what you usually use?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The differences are between function and arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually both are standard ways. You can use any of them and no performance issues are there. however there some advantages of using the code like bellow:

```
const Users = () => {}
export default Users;
```

- This is called arrow function and this is a ES6 feature.
- Arrow syntax automatically binds `this` to the surrounding code’s context
- The syntax allows an implicit return when there is no body block, resulting in shorter and simpler code in some cases
- Last but not least, => is shorter and simpler than function, although stylistic issues are often subjective

So for the best practice and usability, you should go for the `Arrow Function`

For better understanding you can check [This](https://codeutopia.net/blog/2015/01/06/es6-what-are-the-benefits-of-the-new-features-in-practice/#:%7E:text=Arrow%20functions,simpler%20code%20in%20some%20cases)